# Duplicated content in Google. Same subpage different link

Tags: google, seo, duplicate-content

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

At my website I can access published posts by two different types of links. For example http://mysite.com/posts/333 points at the same content as http://mysite.com/check/this-is-news,333 is . How Google search engine will deal with it? Is it example of duplicated content or not?

Answer (score 3):

That is a perfect example of duplicate content. Google will choose which page it considers to be the "main" page and filter out the duplicates. To prevent this from happening you need to use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). This will tell Google which page to include in its index and which pages to associate with the main page as a duplicate. PageRank and backlinks to the duplicate URLs are counted towards the main page.